# Do I really need to require csv gem with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

My question is simple:

Do I have to `require 'csv'` on a class using Ruby on Rails?

If i open a `rails console` and tryied to use CSV gem it works, but do I have to do that in the file?

Comment: Your automated tests pass if you leave out the `require 'csv'`, right?

Comment: yeah, but that ensures that will it works on normal execution?

Comment: Personally I would just to indicated that it is being used in that file. In my experience I work with CSV in a service or lib file and it feels better to add the `require` and give it a more rounded look. This is even more true if the file could be run independent or rails. (I do write ruby scripts without rails)

Comment: It's in the stdlib, not a gem. You can put the require call in application.rb and use it from everywhere

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`CSV` library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) is part of the ruby standard library; it is not a gem (i.e. a third party library).

As with all of the standard library (unlike the *core* library), `csv` is not automatically loaded by the ruby interpreter. So yes, **somewhere** in your application you do need to `require` it:

```
irb(main):001:0> CSV
NameError: uninitialized constant CSV
        from (irb):1
        from /Users/tomlord/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> require 'csv'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> CSV
=> CSV
```

In a large project such as a rails application, you may find that `csv` has actually been already loaded; perhaps somewhere "obscure" like within a gem, or somewhere in `config/initializers/*`, or `config/application.rb`.

However, it's generally a bad idea to rely on libraries being loaded in "unrelated" places like this; doing so could lead to to inadvertently breaking other code when you change it, or gradually loading more and more libraries here, even when some are no longer needed.

So to cut a long story short: Yes, I would recommend writing `require 'csv'` at the top of any file which uses the `CSV` library. Or, within a larger project which will *clearly* need this library loaded and used in many places, you *could* consider just loading it globally in places like `config/application.rb`

Comment: I concur, great answer. Is there a specific con to multiple `require 'csv'`s? From my understanding doing a multiple require would just return `false`. So just the performance hit of Ruby checking if the CSV library is loaded?

Comment: @DaryllSantos Not really; the performance cost of multiple `require`s is negligible (and will only happen when first parsing the file, as you say). The only real "downside" to having multiple `require` statements is cluttering the code - which, again, isn't a big deal for the sake of just one line!

Comment: On the rare occasion that you do need to force re-evaluation of a file, you should use [`load`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-load) instead of `require`.